# Sort DBGrid using column title

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I am using Access database with delphi 7. I have created a DBGrid and am using Adoquery to show database with columns having students ID, Firstname and lastname titles with the exact field names format in the database. I have the following code to sort the column titles in ascending order.

```
procedure TReportsForm.DBGrid2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
str1: String;
begin
str1 := DBGrid2.SelectedField.FieldName;
ADOQuery1.Sort:= str1+' ASC';
end;
```

When I press the firstname and lastname column titles, the sorting works fine. However when I press the students ID results 
I get error the message

EOleException:  Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.

Is this problem associated with numbers and characters fields and how can this be solved?

Comment: What data type is this field?

Comment: the data type are as for students ID is number while the rest is text. Is there a possibility of conflict and how do I avoid this?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `str1` contains the correct field name for ID?

Comment: @kobik Well if it reads the field name directly from the data grid, I would hope it's the correct field name. I think there's something happening that we can't see here, for example perhaps an `OnClick` event or some other event.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the problem.
You see, the function ADOQuery.Sort can be applied to 'WideString' data types. In your database, check what data type student ID is. If it is set as 'number' then obviously ADOQuery.Sort cannot be applied to it, it is an incompatible data type. Try changing the student ID field to 'Text' data type in your database, and retry and see if that works. 
Also quick tip: In your database, if student ID is set as'number' then it might just be worth it to change it to text. BEcause it is a primary key (im assuming) and therefore no calculations are performed on the student ID, therefore it doesn't need to be stored as a number.
Hope this helped! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You never accepted the above answer, so I assume it didn't help.  I was wondering if the issue is with spaces in field names ("Student ID" for example).  If so, the solution is to slightly change the code:

```
ADOQuery1.Sort:= '[' + str1 + '] ASC';
```

Cheers